# Watir-webdriver issue with options.yml file

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

I have been using firewatir for quite some time but thinking of switching to watir-webdriver. I was playing with my existing script and getting an error in the IRB when i use watir-webdriver

Here is my code from existing script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver' 
Watir.options_file = 'classes/options.yml'
```

I am getting a following error

"undefined method `options_file=' for Watir:Module (NoMethodError)"

Can someone point me to the right direction since I am lost on this for couple of days.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watir != Watir-Webdriver. Watir-Webdriver does not support options.yml using options_file, or most likely the options you're setting in it (browser.speed, etc).

You can find a list of available methods, as well as a comparison list of the two here: http://jarib.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/ .

If you post the options you are setting in that file we can help you determine if they're available in Watir-Webdriver, or how else you use them.

Thanks

Comment: The only config options available for Watir.options_file are browser type (redundant - watir only supports IE, Watir-WebDriver uses Browser.new to specify), browser speed and visible, which aren't even supported in Watir-WebDriver, so no need to load this file at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about watir-webdriver at http://watirwebdriver.com/